# Why did the Supreme Court vacate the ruling that Trump could not block Twitter users?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court, social-media

In 2019, an appeals court [upheld](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/legal-issues/president-trump-cannot-block-his-critics-on-twitter-federal-appeals-court-rules/2019/07/09/d07a5558-8230-11e9-95a9-e2c830afe24f_story.html) a decision that President Trump violated the First Amendment by blocking users from his Twitter account.

Two days ago, the Supreme Court declared the case "moot" and [vacated](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/courts_law/supreme-court-trump-twitter-clarence-thomas/2021/04/05/b05686ee-960f-11eb-b28d-bfa7bb5cb2a5_story.html) the appeals court's ruling. An [article](https://www.cnn.com/2021/04/05/politics/supreme-court-trump-twitter-followers/index.html) gives the following reason:

> The high court dismissed the case because Trump is not in office so there is no longer a live case or controversy.

I do not understand this reasoning. Why not leave the appeals court's ruling on the record, because it is always possible a future president will try to block users while communicating with a personal social media account? Now if the issue pops up again in the future, a president will be allowed to block users for multiple years while the issue gets re-litigated from scratch.

Comment: You can find the answer in the opinions given.  Haven't read them personally, but have heard quotes attributed to Justice Clarence Thomas' opinion.

Comment: Additionally, I would reword the question as the decision being vacated means that presidents blocking users from Twitter (or other Politicians.  AOC was sued for blocking users citing this case as precedent ) is not "wrong" or done "wrongly" since the case is now moot.

Comment: It's especially moot since Trump is banned from twitter.

Comment: @hszmv Only Thomas wrote a full opinion, though, and no other justices joined, so there's no "official" reasoning to go off of.

Comment: Sounds like the court heaved a collective groan.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this topic. Why would President Trump be violating the 1st amendment by blocking twitter users? Freedom of speech lets you say what you want, but people aren't forced to tune in to what you say. People not listening to you isn't censorship. Besides regular people block each other on a regular basis with no repercussions. Or am I misunderstanding the wording of the question?

Comment: By the way, your first article is locked behind a $1/week paywall

Comment: @SomeGuy: The court declared that since Trump was making official announcements from his twitter feed, it became an "official government communication channel", and therefore Trump did not have the right to prevent citizens from receiving official government communications.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That is not what the 2nd Circuit based its reasoning on. Anyone can read any public Twitter post without logging in, so blocking has nothing to do with that (i.e. you could just log out or read it in incognito mode). Instead, the 2nd Circuit reasoned, the problem is that blocking people prevents their *replies* from showing up underneath your tweets, which is classic viewpoint discrimination. By selectively blocking people who disagree with him, Trump was (according to the 2nd Circuit) suppressing their speech in a public forum (which he created by sending "official" tweets).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The case was appealed and taken by SCOTUS. Then the case became moot:

- [Trump was banned from Twitter for life](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jackbrewster/2021/02/10/twitter-cfo-trump-wont-ever-be-allowed-back---even-if-he-runs-again-in-2024/), [his account permanently suspended](https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/topics/company/2020/suspension.html). As the Twitter account that was the core of the controversy no longer exists, Trump can't block any accounts anymore. As Trump is disallowed from making a new account, it can't arise with the same fact pattern.
- Trump is no longer in office.

The SCOTUS may only weigh in on **live** and **active** cases of controversy. The case is neither live nor active because it was rendered moot in January. As a result, it had to be dismissed, or the decision to take the case overturned.

Speculating why they chose one over the other is moot, as there is no majority opinion given and the judges won't answer such questions.

Comment: Can you explain, why did they have to dismiss it instead of just declining certiorari.

Comment: @J.Win. they already had granted cert, now the case came up on the schedule again, it had to be dismissed based on the changed facts.

Comment: I did not know this. So, after granting cert, the court has to make a decision, and cannot withdraw the grant?

Comment: yes. The same happened to a gun-law case about NYC last year: the law was repealed, the case became moot.

Comment: They could have dismissed the writ of cert as improvidently granted, which it obviously was. They chose not to, likely because they didn't want to leave the precedent standing. Here's one example of the Supreme Court doing exactly that. [LabCorp v. Metabolite](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/548/124/)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if it was proper or not the court did not decide at all. assuming it was improperly decided is pure speculation.

Comment: @Trish The case becoming moot after cert is granted is one of the most common examples of a situation where cert was deemed improvidently granted. That's not a controversial claim. (As just one example, the Supreme Court did this in Public Employees’
Retirement System of Mississippi v. IndyMac MBS which became moot due to a settlement leaving no party with any interest in contesting or defending the lower court ruling.)

Comment: They can rule on moot cases if its a common enough issue. I.e. that's how abortions were legalized in Wade vs. Roe.

Comment: @JohnathanReez the issue need not be common but "capable of repetition," and, critically, "evading review."  Litigation around pregnancy evades review because a full term pregnancy is considerably shorter than the typical duration of the appellate process.  This test was established a few decades earlier.  See (and note the order of the litigants) the [Wikipedia article on Roe v. Wade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v._Wade) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: @Trish: If the Supreme court dismisses certiorari as improvidently granted, then it was, by definition, improvidently granted.  Dismissing certiorari as improvidently granted is effectively saying, "Oops, we made a mistake." But since granting certiorari is discretionary, they can rightly call anything a mistake even if they merely changed their mind.  Mind you, I imagine justices prefer to declare a case as moot; why would they want to say, "I made a mistake" if they didn't make a mistake?

Comment: @Brian First, that's not true. Something can be later determined to have been done improvidently despite no reason to think so at the time it happened. See the case I cited where they dismissed the writ as improvidently granted because the parties settled after cert was granted leaving nobody with any interest in litigating the case. Second, if they want the precedent to stand, they would dismiss the writ.

Answer (score 20):

The Supreme Court has a lot of things they can do in theory, but in reality, there are only two options the Court likely considered:

One was to simply dismiss the writ of certiorari as improvidently granted due to neither party being significantly affected by the outcome of the case, as they did in Public Employees’ Retirement System of Mississippi v. IndyMac MBS.

The second was to vacate the lower court ruling and remand with instructions to the lower court to dismiss the case. That is what they did in this case.

> Why not leave the appeals court's ruling on the record, because it is always possible a future president will try to block users while communicating with a personal social media account? Now if the issue pops up again in the future, a president will wrongly be allowed to block users for multiple years while the issue gets re-litigated from scratch.

That was their other option. The most obvious explanation for why they didn't pick that option is that the Supreme Court explicitly wanted this result, likely because at least some of them don't agree with your characterization that they would "wrongly be allowed".

I suspect what's going on here is that there is nobody to challenge this ruling in an adversarial situation. So the Supreme Court doesn't want a piece of precedent that resulted only from the administration being changed and would prefer that if there's going to a precedent-setting case on this, that it be aggressively litigated.

So essentially, they didn't want this on the books because it wouldn't get appealed and they weren't convinced it was decided correctly.